# Display specific PHP files in Application Insights

Tags: php, azure, azure-application-insights

We migrated a very old php application to Azure and we have activated Application Insights via the Web App option.

Now we identify some very high request durations (>15s) but we cannot identify which php files are responsible.

In the specific operation information we only see domain.com/folder/ but not the corresponding php file.

What do we have to configure to see which file (=function => domain.com/folder/myfile.php) is responsible in this crappy old php app?

We already in development to replace this app which native Azure functionality, but we need a transition fix now.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned that you enabled App Insights within the Web App, have you added the instrumentation to the app pages?  You can find info on the Application Insights SDK for PHP here:  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP

Comment: @MikeOryszak we dont use the PHP Extension of AppInsights. We cannot edit the code. If you create a WebApp in Azure, Application Insights will be created by default too. This AppInsights Account is automatically attach to the created Web App. For default tracing no additional key is required anymore. Only if you want to have custom insights / telemetry map (we dont have that).

Comment: Got it, I've not used it against a PHP app, but was still under the impression that for more detailed data the telemetry code was required.  To your point, I typically use custom events as well.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with **@Mike Oryszak** , you need to write code to collect custom event in your code.

For that you can simply install the application insight in your code and then

```
$telemetryClient = new \ApplicationInsights\Telemetry_Client();
$context = $telemetryClient->getContext();

// Necessary
$context->setInstrumentationKey('YOUR INSTRUMENTATION KEY');

// Optional
$context->getSessionContext()->setId(session_id());
$context->getUserContext()->setId('YOUR USER ID');
$context->getApplicationContext()->setVer('YOUR VERSION');
$context->getLocationContext()->setIp('YOUR IP');

// Start tracking
$telemetryClient->trackEvent('name of your event');
$telemetryClient->flush();
```

By calling below method , you can log any message in AI telemetry.

```
$telemetryClient->trackEvent('name of your event');
```

Here is how you can send custom telemetry with custom properties.

```
$telemetryClient->trackEvent('name of your event', ['MyCustomProperty' => 42, 'MyCustomProperty2' => 'test'], ['duration', 42]);
```

Sending a request telemetry item with duration, http status code, whether or not the request succeeded, custom properties and measurements.This seems to be the most optimum in your case.

```
$telemetryClient->trackRequest('myRequest', 'http://foo.bar', time(), 3754, 200, true, ['InlineProperty' => 'test_value'], ['duration_inner' => 42.0]);
```

you can look for more samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP).

Hope it helps.